# Why do Nachash נחש & Mashiach משיח have the same Gematria?

Tags: messiah, gematria-numerology

I once heard a beautiful explanation of why נחש nachash & משיח mashiach have the same Gematria of 358 but I can’t recall it. 
Does anyone know what the connection between these two seemingly antithetical forces are? Hopefully someone here will jog my memory!

Comment: I don’t have time to write it up but http://www.parsha.net/Bereishis/Bereishis69.doc gives an explanation.

Comment: זה כנגד זה ברא אלקים

Comment: [A thought of I’m sure many, many others:] Moshiah symbolizes the era when man’s snake-like behavior will be questioned ([Tan. 8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.8a.11?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: Bnei Yissaschar on Chanukah when he explains the secret of the dreidel why it says גשנה (which is also gematria נחש and משיח). See [here](https://parshaponders.com/chanukah-5777/) for an English adaptation.

Comment: I really don’t get why ppl are downvoting this question